# Is the set of all algorithms computable?

Tags: logic, algorithms, computability, reverse-math

Informally, I am basically asking if there is an algorithm that checks if the input is an algorithm or not.

In *Proofs From the Inside Out* by John Stillwell, the author sometimes talks about an enumeration for all algorithms $A_1, A_2, ...$ (e.g., section 4.3 page 76). (The author also does that without giving a formal definition of what an algorithm is!) This makes the set of all algorithms computably enumerable (as he is literally listing all algorithms one by one), and so my first instinct was to ask if such set is computable.

Initially I thought yes! But that would mean there is an algorithm $A'$ that checks if something is an algorithm or not. That already seems very weird. Assuming this is fine, we may run into the following issue: $A'$ must itself belong to the set of all algorithms, and so we would have to make $A'$ an input of $A'$. That is also strange, so I thought I come to StackExchange for some help.

Comment: I think they only assume that the set of algorithm is countable. Typically they are defined by some finite dimensional state machine, and few functions from some finite set to some other finite set. As such there is countably many of those and so you can index them with the natural numbers.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with making $A'$ an input of $A'$. An algorithm is generally defined as a computing process (on a Turing machine) that halts for any input. With this definition, no such algorithm exist since the halting problem is undecidable. However, the set of Turing machines that halts is countable, so in some contexts, we are allowed to list them (though it is not possible algorithmically)

Comment: It is computable. (Or, to be more precise, there is a way to encode algorithms so that the set they form is computable.) And it isn’t really strange that an algorithm can take its own code as input. As an example, your computer essentially already has such an algorithm, which is how it can run various programs. (Because to do so, your computer already has to recognize that something is an executable program and then interpret and run it.) You can also code a program, then feed it its own code.

Comment: @caduk I feel like algorithms are not generally required to halt? If they are required to halt then certainly the set they form is no longer computable. If they are allowed to not halt, that’s a different matter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This depends on the definition of "algorithms". If as stated informally in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm) (often used in introductory algorithm courses),

> Starting from an initial state and initial input (perhaps empty),the instructions describe a computation that, when executed, proceeds through a finite number of well-defined successive states, eventually producing "output" and terminating at a final ending state.

Then the answer is definitely no, because an algorithm that determines whether an input is an algorithm as above would be able to solve the halting problem.

However, if the definition of algorithms are essentially [partial recursive functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_recursive_function), then definitely yes. To give a "proof", "algorithms" can be defined as well-formed C++ programs, then a C++ compiler (with minimal change to produce a boolean output instead of machine code and error messages) is an algorithm to determine whether an input text is an algorithm. Note that we can write a C++ compiler in C++, so the "C++ compiler" could be understood as a well-formed C++ program which is by our definition an algorithm.

As $A'$ can be made an input of $A'$, there is no surprise at all. If you write down a program $P$ that takes a string and returns a string with all empty spaces deleted, you can enter $P$ itself into $P$. This kind of self-reference (and more subtle ones) is frequently used in TCS, such as to show the halting problem is undecidable. If it makes you more comfortable, the execution of an algorithm (which might be understood as a physical process involving hardware) is different from an algorithm (a text).

For more fun, it was a famous challenge to write down [a program that prints itself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)).

Comment: Not to mention, brainfuck is Turing-complete, and a valid brainfuck program is any string whose `[` and `]` are balanced. So checking whether a string is a valid brainfuck program can be done by a push-down automaton.

Comment: IIRC, C++'s grammar is actually undecidable, so it's perhaps not the best example. A good example is [Jot](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Jot), for which the set of valid programs is just the set of binary strings.

Comment: @user76284 [Good point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794015/what-do-people-mean-when-they-say-c-has-undecidable-grammar)! Other than [Brainfuck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) and Jot, we can also use $\lambda$-calculus etc.

Answer (score 1):

Following Turing’s insights and suggestions, it is reasonable to define an algorithm as a finite set of instructions as expressed using some finite expression (string) of some language with an enumerable alphabet. Since the set of all finite strings of an enumerable language is enumerable itself, it follows that the set of all algorithms as expressed by that language is enumerable.

Notice that this does not require that you can tell, given any expression from that language, whether that describes an algorithm or not. That depends on the exact definition of an algorithm as expressed in that language. In most practical cases, though, you can. For example, it’s straightforward to decide whether some string of symbols is a program in accordance to some specific programming language.